# How to set delay properly in android (Eclipse)

Tags: android

im new at eclipse and at making applications and i wanted to create infinite loop with 3 pictures that every picture will turn visible or invisible in his turn.
but when i run the application only the second picture become visible once and that's it, then is stop and noting happen.
what i need to do to get it to work?

```js
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   
  dk1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dkmain1);
  dk2 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dkmain2);
  dk3 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dkmain3);
  dk1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     dk2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     dk3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
   
    if(dk1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
    {    
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {                
               dk1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            dk2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dk3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);             
                         }
                     }, 2000);            
    }
    if(dk2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
    { 
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {                                  
                  dk1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         dk2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         dk3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                      
              }
          }, 2000);
    }
    if(dk3.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
    { 
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {                              
                  dk1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         dk2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         dk3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                         
              }
          }, 3000);   
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make the `Handlers` **nested** to make sure they run one by one :

```
    if(dk1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {           
                     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {                 
                            dk1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            dk2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            dk3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            //put your 2nd if here, and 3rd if INSIDE your 2nd if
                            if(dk2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) 
                            //rest of the 2nd if code, and out the 3rd if here
                             }
                         }, 2000);
```

Comment: when i run it like you did, the pictures switch only once. how i do it infinite?

Comment: Does it run until the 3rd picture? If yes, then i think you only need to add while(true) and put the whole code inside it. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: BTW, i think your main question : "How to set delay properly" has already been answered :)

Comment: now when i put the code inside a while noting is running, all i get is an empty page including the pictures. and thanks for the answers

Comment: @Ofeknourian Sorry i cant help other than the while(true). You may want to create a new question like "how to run handler as long as activity is active?"

Comment: @Ofeknourian just to make thing clear, its not i dont want to help but i dont know how to do that. You can create a new question specifically for asking that :)

Comment: A random downvote without any critic?hmm...(im not talking to thread starter :))

Answer (score 0):

If you set the view invisible:

```
dk2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Then check if it's visible:

```
if(dk2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
```

It will always evaluate to false and will never be executed.

I would consider a different approach such as:

- Timer - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html
- CountDownTimer - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Also, you can set the default visibility in the layout using:

```
android:visibility="visible|invisible|gone"
```